# User can't be cast to to com.example.security.CustomUserDetails Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to set my user on to a course object that I created and I keeping getting the error `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.example.security.CustomUserDetails` I know I'm getting the user details from the session, because when I run it in debug mode I can see the name of the currently logged in user, so I think I'm somewhat close to a solution.

Here's my Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="createCourse", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createCoursePost (@ModelAttribute Course course, Long userId, ModelMap model, Authentication auth)
{   
    CustomUserDetails myUserDetails = (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    userId = myUserDetails.getUser().getId();

    User user = userRepo.findOne(userId);

    course.setUser(user);

    courseRepo.save(course);


    return "redirect:/courses";
}
```

Here's my UserDetailsServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

@Transactional
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.example.domain.User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getRoles());

    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

}

private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.example.domain.User user,
                                        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRoleName()));
    }

    return new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

}
```

Here's my customUserDetails, it's possible that me getting and setting the user could be redundant, but I saw an example with this, and so I'm not really sure what to do with this.

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails{

private User user;

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2020921373107176828L;

public CustomUserDetails () {}

public CustomUserDetails (User user) {
    super(user);
}

@Override
public Set<Authorities> getAuthorities() {
    return super.getAuthorities();
}
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

Here's my webSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static PasswordEncoder encoder;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());

    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/register", "/courses", "/editCourse", "/sets", "/search", "/viewCourse/{courseId}", "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf","fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff", "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff", "/viewCourse/post/{postId}").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http
    .formLogin()
         .loginPage("/login")
         .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
         .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/loggedout")
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1);


}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    if(encoder == null) {
        encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    return encoder;
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() 
{ 
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository(); 
    repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
    return repository; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this just in case anyone else sees this.  I think my problem was that I wasn't returning userdetails in the userdetailsimpl class. And I also had to update my controller. So here's my new code

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="createCourse", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createCoursePost (@ModelAttribute Course course, Long userId, ModelMap model)
{   
    CustomUserDetails myUserDetails = (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    userId = myUserDetails.getUser().getId();

    User user = userRepo.findOne(userId);

    course.setUser(user);

    courseRepo.save(course);


    return "redirect:/courses";
}
```

And userDetailsServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

@Transactional
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.example.domain.User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);

    CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = new CustomUserDetails(user);
    customUserDetails.setUser(user);

    return customUserDetails;
}
}
```