# Spring security User cannot be casted to class user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Firstly please bare in mind I am a Java noob and this is all unexplored territory for me.

I have followed a guide (roughly 6 months old) to implement spring security, I have never found a guide configured to work specifically with a separate frontend layer.

Every step worked right up until implementing tokens and I get spat this error:

```
class org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to class com.example.springboot.model.User
```

I have seen other posts on here which are similar though they discuss different

eg.

1. [User can't be cast to to com.example.security.CustomUserDetails Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055369/user-cant-be-cast-to-to-com-example-security-customuserdetails-spring-security) - this discusses not returning an entity
2. [Spring security Userdetails cannot be cast to my own user implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876243/spring-security-userdetails-cannot-be-cast-to-my-own-user-implementation) - Discusses a wrong import statement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`, in JwtAuthenticationFilter class

Firstly, I use
`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.userDetails` (similar to the guide author)

Secondly, I have three instances of where this this provider is outlined (2 `userDetails` and 1 `userDetailsService`)

1x `userDetails` in `JWTAuthenticationFilter`

1x `userDetailsService` in `JWTAuthenticationFilter`

1x `userDetails` in `JWTTokenHelper`

This is the endpoint:

```
    @PostMapping("/auth/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authenticationRequest.getUserName(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        User user=(User)authentication.getPrincipal(); // crashes here
        String jwtToken=jWTTokenHelper.generateToken(user.getUsername());

        LoginResponse response=new LoginResponse();
        response.setToken(jwtToken);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

Which returns an error on the commented line, drilling further and looking at the following class, it hits the first if statement (which I think is if its not null?)

Then goes to filterChain.doFilter and crashes

JWTAuthenticationFilter as shown below:

```
package com.example.springboot.config;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private JWTTokenHelper jwtTokenHelper;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, JWTTokenHelper jwtTokenHelper) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.jwtTokenHelper = jwtTokenHelper;

    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authToken = jwtTokenHelper.getToken(request);
        if (null != authToken) { // fails this check
            String userName = jwtTokenHelper.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
            if (null != userName) {
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
                if (jwtTokenHelper.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response); // returns error here
    }
}
```

JWTTokenHelper as shown below:

```
package com.example.springboot.config;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

@Component
public class JWTTokenHelper {

    @Value("${jwt.auth.app}")
    private String appName;

    @Value("${jwt.auth.secret_key}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${jwt.auth.expires_in}")
    private int expiresIn;

    private SignatureAlgorithm SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

    public JWTTokenHelper(String appName, String secretKey, int expiresIn, SignatureAlgorithm SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM) {
        this.appName = appName;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
        this.SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM;
    }

    public JWTTokenHelper() { }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        Claims claims;
        try {
            claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(secretKey)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            claims = null;
        }
        return claims;
    }

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        String username;
        try {
            final Claims claims = this.getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
            username = claims.getSubject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            username = null;
        }
        return username;
    }

    public String generateToken(String username) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setIssuer( appName )
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(generateExpirationDate())
                .signWith( SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM, secretKey )
                .compact();
    }

    private Date generateExpirationDate() {
        return new Date(new Date().getTime() + expiresIn * 1000);
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (
                username != null &&
                        username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) &&
                        !isTokenExpired(token)
        );
    }

    public boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        Date expireDate=getExpirationDate(token);
        return expireDate.before(new Date());
    }


    private Date getExpirationDate(String token) {
        Date expireDate;
        try {
            final Claims claims = this.getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
            expireDate = claims.getExpiration();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            expireDate = null;
        }
        return expireDate;
    }


    public Date getIssuedAtDateFromToken(String token) {
        Date issueAt;
        try {
            final Claims claims = this.getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
            issueAt = claims.getIssuedAt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            issueAt = null;
        }
        return issueAt;
    }

    public String getToken( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        String authHeader = getAuthHeaderFromHeader( request );
        if ( authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return authHeader.substring(7);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String getAuthHeaderFromHeader( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        return request.getHeader("Authorization");
    }
}
```

This implementation is considerably long (14 classes) for something described a "simple implementation" and I am clueless which part is causing errors. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! :)

EDIT:

After looking more it seems like the get token method fails here:
[image]

EDIT2:
Custom userDetailsService class:

```
package com.example.springboot.service;

import com.example.springboot.model.User;
import com.example.springboot.repository.UserDetailsRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CustomUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDetailsRepository.findByUserName(username);
        if (user != null){ return user; }
        else{ throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Incorrect username:" + username); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you create your own UserDetailsService implementation?

Comment: @AndreyGrigoriev Yes, its named CustomUserService and implements UserDetailsService. 

I have updated the post to include this class. The class it is calling (userDetailsRepository) only has a single method respective of the find by username which extends JPA

Comment: Please take a look at samples in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server. You introduce complexity where it shouldn't be. You don't need any JWTAuthenticationFilter or JWTTokenHelper, just a simple Spring Security configuration class. As for the error you get - it happens because you didn't register your CustomUserService in AuthenticationManagerBuilder

Comment: Spring Security has its own implementation of `UserDetails` which is `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`, and this is the implementation that you are returning in the `UserDetailsService`. However, in your controller, you are trying to cast the Spring Security's implementation to your `com.example.springboot.model.User`. Please that a look at the imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Marcus Hert da Coregio

org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User, and this is the implementation that you are returning in the UserDetailsService. However, in your controller, you are trying to cast the Spring Security's implementation to your com.example.springboot.model.User. Please that a look at the imports

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
```

Though other issues were encountered with this guide